# PayPal API - Initiate Monthly Bill?

Tags: paypal

If I have an "Automatic Billing" button setup on my site, which API can be used to set the variable billing amount and initiate the bill? Want I the API to do is described here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/manage-billing-plans/

I can't find this specifically anywhere but I'm not sure if it's lost in the different terminology between the PayPal API docs and the front-end - I say that because it's seems there is no such thing as Automated Billing in the API docs!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're wanting to use the REST API then look at [Billing Plans](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/billing-plans-and-agreements/).

If you want to use the Classic API look at [Recurring Paymments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/).

Answer (score 0):

To further the accepted answer, I could not achieve what I wanted - it seems that "Automatic Billing" cannot be triggered via an API. You need to create a billing plan, then create an agreement based on the plan, then execute the agreement.

From Andrew's answer, first I got an access token. In my cURLless environment, I did this:

```
//sandbox
$clientid = "AbFnq7P52jf6AUWpu.....";
$secret   = "ECfJRJBDnA26VVNAq.....";
$url = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token';
$auth = base64_encode($clientid . ":" . $secret);

$data = array(
    'grant_type' => 'client_credentials'
);

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Basic {$auth}\r\nAccept: application/json\r\nAccept-Language: en_US\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($data)
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);

$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$arr = json_decode($result, true);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr); echo "</pre>";

$accesstoken = $arr['access_token'];
```

Then followed the "Integration Steps" https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/billing-plans-and-agreements/#integration-steps

I made my cURLless API calls like this (create plan example):

```
$url = 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans/';

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Authorization: Bearer {$accesstoken}\r\nContent-Type: application/json\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => '{
  "name": "Test Plan",
  "description": "My first test plan",
  "type": "INFINITE",
  "payment_definitions": [
         {
            "name": "Regular payment definition",
            "type": "REGULAR",
            "type":"REGULAR",
            "frequency":"Month",
            "amount":{
               "currency":"AUD",
               "value":"100.00"
            },
            "cycles":"0",
            "charge_models":[
               {
                  "type":"TAX",
                  "amount":{
                     "currency":"AUD",
                     "value":"0.00"
                  }
               },
               {
                  "type":"SHIPPING",
                  "amount":{
                     "currency":"AUD",
                     "value":"0.00"
                  }
               }
            ],
            "frequency_interval":"1"
         }
      ],
  "merchant_preferences": {
  "setup_fee": {
    "value": "0",
    "currency": "AUD"
  },
  "return_url": "http://www.paypal.com",
  "cancel_url": "http://www.paypal.com/cancel",
  "auto_bill_amount": "YES",
  "initial_fail_amount_action": "CONTINUE",
  "max_fail_attempts": "0"
  }
}'
    )
);
$context  = stream_context_create($options);
$result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$arr = json_decode($result, true);
echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr); echo "</pre>";
```

Hopefully these snippets will save someone the hours I spent!